Error if refreshed from any other page (or route) other than "/" in react application created with vite@latest (Under deployment on Vercel)
I have developed a single page react app using vite@latest, my problem is that:  If I refresh from the "/" page (or route) then nothing goes wrong, BUT if I refresh from a page(or route) other than "/" , then it shows this error:
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: bom1::xtmxr-1724785922648-b7b9de6eca9f


This problem occurs only on deployment (at Vercel), not in development i.e not in localhost:8000
I tried to search the solution in Vercel documentation, but couldn't find it

I am very sorry , i edited the post , kindly revisit .
